# Notepad++ RegEx Search/Replace: How to append and prepend a character at start and end of each file line?

Tags: regex, search, csv, replace, notepad++

How to append and prepend a character at start and end of each file line?

I have this file structure:

```
140","Bosnia
160","Croatia
170","Serbia
180","Montenegro
200","Slovenia
```

What I need is to add a double quote " at the start and at the end of each file line, using regular expressions in Notepad++ editor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just search for

```
(.*)
```

and replace with

```
"\1"
```

with regular expression option activated. Regular expressions are working only on a row bases, so `(.*)` matches the complete row and because of the brackets around you can access the match using `\1`.

Answer (score 5):

Try searching `^(.*)$` and replacing by `"$1"`.

bye ;)

Comment: It has to be a `\1` in Notepad++, the `$1` is inserted literally.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the whole, even an empty line, with

```
^.*$
```

You can match a non-empty line with

```
^.+$
```

You may match a non-blank line with

```
^\h*\S.*$
```

Now, all you need to do to wrap these lines with any text of your choice, you need to use the **backreference to the whole match** (see [Replace with whole match value using Notepad++ regex search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505400)):

```
"$0"
"$&"
"$MATCH"
"${^MATCH}"
```

If you need to wrap the whole line with parentheses, you will need to escape them since `(` and `)` are "special" in the Notepad++ replacement pattern, `\($&\)`.

Whenever you need to insert a *backslash*, make sure you double it, `\\$&\\`.