# Replace with whole match value using Notepad++ regex search and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using the following expression:

*Find what*: `[0-9]`

But what should I write in *Replace with* field if I want to add specific `sup` tag to all the digits?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you, please, provide *some examples*? Add, please, specify the language (C#, Java, Perl…)

Comment: it's html (I am editing HTML source code in notepad++)

Comment: `<sup>$0</sup>` - that is all.

Comment: Use solution that @WiktorStribiżew suggested, but you should also change the search to `[0-9]+` (or `\d+`) for cleaner HTML.

Comment: @Tadas, Please consider accepting the answer once you are back.

Answer (score 4):

The replacement can be

```
<sup>$0</sup>
```

or

```
<sup>$&</sup>
```

Note that the `$0` / `${0}` / `$&`, or even `$MATCH` and `${^MATCH}` backrefrence inserts the whole match.

See the [**Substitutions**](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Substitutions) section:

> `$&`, `$MATCH`, `${^MATCH}`
>           The whole matched text.

and

> `$n`, `${n}`, `\n`
>    
>       Returns what matched the subexpression numbered n. Negative indices are not alowed.

Note that a match value is usually stored as Group 0 inside a match object.

**However**, `\0` as of now does not work (Notepad++ v.6.9), it looks like it is treated as a NUL character and truncates the replacement pattern right at the location where it is located.